# Запись в файл дополнительной информации

Tags: php

На сайте, который я делаю, у пользователей есть возможность загружать файлы на сайт, а так же у пользователей есть возможность удалять эти файлы. Файлы сохраняются для каждого пользователя в отдельную папку.

**Задача:**

*когда пользователь выбирает файл который он хочет загрузить, нужно добавить возможность поставить отметку, что файл нельзя будет удалить в будущем с сайта.*

**Проблема:**

*я не знаю как пометить файл что-бы потом его можно было распознать что он не удаляемый.*

Я знаю что можно записывать в БД информацию по файлам, но мне не нужно так усложнять, мне нужно сделать всё очень просто, что-бы в самом файле хранилась эта информация. Я почитал документацию по PHP, про изменение атрибутов файла, нашёл там функции xattr_set, xattr_get, но они устанавливаются в PHP как расширение, установить расширение я не могу, админ будет в понедельник, мне нужно сделать сегодня, сейчас =). Подскажите пожалуйста как решить мою проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При сохранения файла, переименуйте его название, добавив какой-нибудь суффикc, например, _persist

```
file.txt => file_persist.txt
```

В дальнейшем ориентируйтесь на присутствие или отсутствие этого суффикса.

**UPD** Как вариант убирайте права на запись у файла при помощи chmod(), однако, этот вариант менее надежен, так как эту информацию можно в последствии потерять, например, при переносе файлов на другой сервер.

Comment: Этот вариант я обдумывал, но у меня и так к имени файла подставляется информация о пользователе. Других вариантов больше нету?

Comment: С другими вариантами у вас могут быть проблемы при переносе файлов с одного сервера/хранилища в другое - можно потерять эту информацию. Можно разбивать несколько суффиксов _user_persist.txt при помощи explode() и анализировать полученный массив.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду что можно потерять информацию атрибутов?

Comment: Да. Если например, вы сохраняете файл не на жесткий диск, а в какое-то хранилище, то у вас появляется возможность снабдить файл дополнительными атрибутами, некоторые файловые системы также это позволяют сделать. Да просто можете убрать права доступа на запись у защищенного файла, а у всех остальных оставить. Однако, не факт, что эта информация сохранится при переезде. Имя файла - сохранится.

Comment: Всё таки вы меня убедили сделать по вашему совету, спасибо!